# Finding the dialog a silverlight FrameworkElement lives in?

Tags: c#, silverlight, dialog, frameworkelement

I have a silverlight app consisting of several dialogs each with a collection of `FrameworkElement`s in it.

Is it possible to find the dialog in which a Framework element is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `VisualTreeHelper`. The code below is what I use to find the `Page` in a WPF application. You can replace Page with whatever container you need in Silverlight, maybe `Popup`.

```
var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
    while (!(parent is Page))
    {
        parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/55369/142519.aspx has a method to simplify the above example code and make it generic-friendly:

```
public static class ControlFinder
{
    public static T FindParent<T>(this UIElement control) where T: UIElement
    {
        UIElement p = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control) as UIElement;
        if (p != null)
        {
            if (p is T)
                return p as T;
            else
                return ControlFinder.FindParent<T>(p);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
var page = myElement.FindParent<Page>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. If you know the structure of your control, then you can user `FrameworkElement.GetParent()` or else you can use [Tree-traversal algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) like BFS or DFS to find the your framework element.